# Can you communicate future information through the event horizon?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, quantum-tunneling

According to Hawking on "Particle Creation by Black Holes", there exists a relationship between the entropy outside of an event horizon, flux within the event horizon, and the area of that same event horizon.

Therefore a black hole can absorb a negatively charged **-EDIT: negative energy-** particle, and in exchange it's positive partner radiates off into infinity and in exchange contributes to an increase background radiation. In exchange its event horizon shrinks after eating the negative particle, balancing it out.

It must also be able to emit those particles too, according to Hawking.

http://www.itp.uni-hannover.de/~giulini/papers/BlackHoleSeminar/Hawking_CMP_1975.pdf

It then gets too math-heavy for me to understand.

You could conceivably just continue to expand and contract the event horizon by tunneling particles through the event horizon until it contracts down enough that you could tunnel your specific particle back.

So basically information cannot be lost in black holes, just stored until it radiates enough particles off that it collapses and releases the particle that tunneled in.

The particle that tunneled would have to get extremely close to the edge of the event horizon, with the distance from it dictating how long before the event horizon expands towards it and it tunnels through.

With this in mind, wouldn't you technically be pulling information out of the future, since the particle that did tunnel had experienced way more time than the observer looking at it, and then tunneled back to greet him, the same particle $\ P $ that went in, except 'older'?

If so, why the hell can a particle interact with the future? Is it interacting with another part of the universe that is further away from the black hole than time cannot propagate enough to 'catch up'? Is it in a different universe?

Comment: I think you mean positive and negative energy, not charge, in the second paragraph.

Comment: Where do you get the idea from that the particle that enters a black hole has some kind of independent existence from the other particles in there? That would require that you could distinguish it somehow, which is not possible. What you really need to do is count states of the black hole as a whole.

Comment: @CuriousOne Since information cannot be permanently lost in the black hole, collapsing the states into one, you just keep manipulating the energy levels within the event horizon, and your information particle would leak out. You would need to have returned the black hole to the excitement level it was in before injection. And no, you'd only need to track the state changes after the information injection, so that you could reverse it. The state it changes into would be a function of the energy input, so your one particle would change the state by x.

Comment: ARMATAV: For all practical purposes information is lost in nature all the time. I can pour a drop of milk in my coffee and it would be impossible for you or anyone else in the universe to collect the molecules of that drop of milk back the way they were. In reality you can't even keep two electrons separate unless you have a potential barrier, which requires, at least, a classical magnetic field (which is a non-existing construct). So the core of the black hole debate is really all about state counting. What is the number of quantum mechanical states of a black hole?

Comment: @CuriousOne You see, I disagree with that inherently based on what Hawking says. Your information does not disappear because you dropped milk in coffee, your information decays infinitely quickly based on the entropy it'll undergo after you drop your milk in coffee. If you were to immediately suspend the reaction state, time-wise (to an observer) just after the drop; you would simply have to move the reaction back a single state to retrieve it. In this case, the separation reference would be the event horizon, and its time difference inside and outside. After energy injection, it'll be 1 + x.

Comment: @ARMATAV: What you are looking for violates the laws of thermodynamics (i.e. it would require my coffee to have a temperature of 0K). Everything we have learned about the internal structure of black holes theoretically assumes that thermodynamics is not violated. Not even Hawking believes that. The only viable question here is how do black hole states "fill up" while we are populating them with particles?

Comment: @CuriousOne It was an analogy. In context of a black hole, the 'reversal' would be an injection of the opposing polarity energy that you initially tunneled in. In theory, we would not be able to observe the time difference between the injected particle and our clock. And in theory it wouldn't matter, because the event horizon separates it such that we observe a 'freeze' for everything near it. Inject, observe states; come back see your particle just recently injected, at which point you inject the opposite polarity until you collapse the event horizon enough to free your particle. Legal.

Comment: @ARMATAV: Analogies don't help you much in statistical mechanics. Either you know the symmetries and then you can count, or you don't. The truth is that we don't know what the internal microscopic structure of a black hole looks like. Moreover, we don't know what the quantum gravity vacuum looks like that they are connected to. You can't just drop something into a black hole and then not expect it to radiate gravitational waves, which you have to take into account if you want to talk about actual information. If you don't collect the gravitational waves, you lost something, already.

Comment: @CuriousOne on the filling up thing; I'll guess that you could change excitement state through the injection of energy in the first place, and then you could weigh it against cosmic background radiation before and after to keep track of the initial injection state. Then you reverse it until you end up with the first internal/external energy level inside and outside of the event horizon. (You would be using your particles that you injected as a 'measurement' of change in internal energy)

Comment: @ARMATAV: Please demonstrate your method (at least theoretically) on a cup of coffee, then we can scale up to black holes. Fair?

Comment: @CuriousOne check the other posts. You aren't randomly throwing chairs and tables into the black hole, if you check the paper there's a distinct relationship between absorption and emission of particles and their associated polarity. You wouldn't care about the gravitational waves right then because you'd be keeping track of the energy change and radiation, while the black hole regulates the area of it's event horizon such that no real gravitational wave change occurs unless it passes the point where it can no longer sustain particles in versus -(particles out).

Comment: @CuriousOne First, prove your cup of coffee exists.

Comment: @ARMATAV: Please go back to my first couple of posts and think about them for a little while. Maybe then the problem will become more obvious.

Comment: Like I was saying, if you're going to reason by analogy instead of transitioning to logic through correlative math and theory; don't flip out when you lose to a requirement of proof as absurd as the one you just posed two points up. As soon as you want to work through it instead of backing out at the slightest overstepping of your 'reasoning' and refusing to allow for creative thought in a problem that is almost entirely based on hypotheses; post again. Until then I'm done, you aren't reasoning past my conjecture, you're dodging it.

Comment: @ARMATAV: assuming cosmic censorship, the black hole mass and no-hair theorems already tell us that in a general merger event, you will generically have to have information trasmitted away from the hole via gravitational waves.  It's not ridiculous to say (info in) -> (info in waves) + (info in hole).  But once you've radiated things away and chosen retarded solutions, you're breaking the time reversal scenario that you're going for.